# For loop with variable step size - C++

Tags: c++, for-loop

I want to use a for loop with variable step size, in particular I want that the `i` variable in `for` loop is equal to:

1. All numbers except the ones which can be divided by `3` so:

> i = 1-2-4-5-7-8-10-11-13-14-16-17...

2. All numbers except the ones which can be divided by `3` and `2` so:

> i = 1-5-7-11-13-17...

The base code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int N = 100;
    for ( int i=0; i<N; i++) { //<-----
        //instructions
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible with `for` loop?

Comment: did you ever try to replace `i++` with something else ?

Comment: Add another check inside the loop for the special conditions? Use a variable when incrementing (like e.g. `i += x` where `x` is the amount to increment)? The last part of the `for` loop is a normal expression.

Comment: btw for loops with "variable step size" are often more complicated than it needs to be, sometimes while loops are more appropriate when you dont iterate in fixed steps

Comment: One obvious generalization is a loop variable that only takes on prime numbers. Testing each number for primality can be expensive. But there's a beautiful example for Lucid (a dataflow language) of how to feed the generated prime numbers back to form a sieve that aids in generating each next number. Anyway, if you want more than just special purpose code, but some insight, then this is one good direction to explore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using ternary operators. It makes the readability of your code more difficult (my opinion, but some people like it), but you put everything inside your `for` statement.

For the numbers that can be divided by 3, for instance:

```
for (int i = 1; i < N; i = (((i+1)%3 == 0) ? i+2 : i+1)) {
    //Instructions
}
```

And, for numbers that can be divided by 3 and 2, you could try this:

```
for (int i = 1; 
 i < N; 
 i = (i+1)%3 == 0 || ((i+1)%2) == 0 ? 
     ((i+2)%3 == 0 || i%2 == 0 ? 
        (i%3 == 0 || (i+1)%2 == 0 ? i+4 : i+3) : i+2 ) : i+1) {
    //Instructions
}
```

For more information about ternary operators, click [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/14631/)

**EDIT** Adding @AMA's suggestion, from comments (simpler than mine)

```
for (int i = 1; 
     i < N; 
     i = (i+1)%2 == 0 
         ? (i+2)%3 == 0
             ? i+4
             : i+2
         : (i+1)%3 == 0 
             ? i+2
             : i+1) {
    //Instructions
}
```

Comment: May not be the best approach, but that's what I was looking for

Comment: @UgoMela also not the working one. Lets say `i` is 1, `(i+1)%2` is true, so `i` becomes 3, which obviously is wrong, as it's a multiple of 3.

Comment: @AMA the main target of the answer was to show an option that contains everything on the `for` statement and present ternary operators. Since there were several others that were using `if` and `continue` inside the code blocks, I thought it would add something - apparently Ugo liked it. Anyway, thanks for pointing the logic error - it should be fixed now.

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado sure you're welcome. I was not down-voting the answer by the way.

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado but your code would not compile, and after typos are fixed still would not work :) see [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EyvfsZ6daa1zHFvL). I am afraid there is no way around implementing a proper increment function (which uses a loop internally) without ending-up with an abomination of a forzilla-cycle

Comment: Ok, now fixed :)

Comment: But that's an interesting puzzle for sure. [Here's my take](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LDQfyPszkHQeksL0)

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado oups, we forgot that the loop should start from 1.

Answer (score 4):

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    if(i % 3 == 0) // if(i % 3 == 0 || i % 2 == 0) // if(is_skippable(i))
        continue;
    //instructions
}
```

Comment: I am preferring this solution over the one from mkrufky (although it will work), because I think it is more expressive and easier to read.

Comment: I've posted an answer (the accepted one), but I need to tell, I would use this solution over mine...

Answer (score 1):

Use an `if` conditional statement and **`continue`**.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i ++)
{
    if (i % 3 == 0)
        continue;
    do_stuff();
}
```

The `continue` statement **skips the rest of current loop and go to next loop immediately**, so that should work for you. In the above example, if variable `i` is divided by 3, the `continue` will skip everything after it, and `do_stuff` will not be executed.

You can use multiple `continue`s in one loop, any one of them will skip the current loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i ++)
{
    if (i % 3 == 0)
        continue;
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        continue; // Another continue
    do_stuff();
}
```

Well let's make it simple:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i ++)
{
    if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 2 == 0)
        continue;
    do_stuff();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the `i++` from the `for` statement and increment the counter based on your algorithm for "not divisible by three" inside the loop.   ...or if the logic is simple enough, replace the `i++` with your increment algorithm.

Comment: Why the downvote?  The question asks, "Is it possible with for loop?" and I've answered that question.

Comment: Doing the increment from within the loop skips the test in the for () statement, maybe?  Might as well use a for(;;) statement.

Comment: again, the question asked, "Is it possible with for loop?"   ...a `for(;;)` statement is indeed a for loop.  I actually answered the question asked.  All the other answers here are implementations.  The answer to the OP is "Yes."

Answer (score 0):

The job of the third term in the `for` loop is to provide the next value for the loop control variable. It's most common form is simply an increment: `++i`, but it can be more complex. You can write the various expressions that are in some of the other answers, but they're hard to read, and, as always, hard-to-read code often means you need to write a function:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i = next(i))
```

where `next(i)` has been defined to look something like this:

```
int next(int i) {
    ++i;
    if (i % 3 == 0)
        ++i;
    return i;
}
```

Comment: same comment as to the other answer: one does not need to check for each single integer whether it is divisible by three or not, because there is a simple pattern. However, here I would accept readability over efficiency, but at least write a comment. I mean it is rather rare that one can save almost 2/3 of the work that easily...

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: As [tobi303](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4117728/tobi303) and [Michaël Roy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2430669/micha%C3%ABl-roy) suggested in the comments that this method is not CPU firendly/efficient and is costly. So, you might want to look at other alternatives unless readablility is what you are looking for.

Since, you specifically mentioned to change the steps so...

For the first part I would try something like this:

**1. Skipping numbers divisible by 3**

```
 for (int i = 1; i < N; i = i + 1 + ((i + 1) % 3 == 0)) {   
    //instructions
 }
```

**2. Skipping numbers divisible by 2 *or* 3** (*'or'* because this is what your example depicts):

```
for (int i = 1; i < N; i = i + 2 + 2 * ((i + 2) % 3 == 0)) {
    //instructions
}
```

Working Example. [Ideone](https://ideone.com/h7GuFt)

**Note**: Do take care of the initial value of 'i'. It is 1 not 0.

**PS**: In your first example, 15 shouldn't be there.

Comment: its a waste of cpu to check every integer for its remainder mod 3. There is a simple pattern, no need to use `%` or to check for each number if it has to be skipped. If it was for readability over efficiency I would buy it, but imho thats not the case here (...same for the second case)

Comment: @dark_escape Depending on the architecture, an integer division can take 40 to 80 clock cycles.

Comment: @tobi303 thanks for informing. I've made an edit stating your point. :)

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For a more modern c++ style you can also use a `lambda` to define an advance function. That is not strictly  necessary (`advance3` and `advance23` below could be just regular functions) but it helps show your intention close to where you use the `advance` functions.

Please note that the following will include `0`, since `0%n == 0`. If you want to exclude `0`, just start your loop from `1`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N = 100;

    auto advance3 = []( int &i ){ i++; while( i % 3 == 0 ) { i++;} };

    for ( int i=0; i<N; advance3( i ) ){ 
        cout << i << ", ";
    }
    cout << '\n';


    auto advance23 = []( int &i ){ i++; while( ( i % 3 == 0 ) || ( i % 2 == 0 ) ) { i++;}  };

    for ( int i=0; i<N; advance23( i ) ){ 
        cout << i << ", ";
    }
    cout << '\n';

    return 0;    
}
```