# Clang warning about static templated constexpr (inline function is not defined)

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I have the following c++ code:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

typedef unsigned char uchar;

class A {
public:
    template <size_t N, uchar value>
    static inline constexpr std::array<uchar, N> filledArray() {
        std::array<uchar,N> ret{};
        ret.fill(value);
        return ret;
    }

    std::array<uchar, 5> upper = A::filledArray<5, 'A'>();
};

int main() {
    A blah;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        std::cout << blah.upper[i] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

g++ compiles it without warnings and the output is As, as expected.
but clang++-4.0 produces:

```
clang++-4.0 -std=c++14 main.cpp -o clangOut
main.cpp:9:47: warning: inline function 'A::filledArray<5, 'A'>' is not defined [-Wundefined-inline]
        static inline constexpr std::array<uchar, N> filledArray() {
                                                    ^
main.cpp:15:34: note: used here
        std::array<uchar, 5> upper = A::filledArray<5, 'A'>();
                                        ^
1 warning generated.
/tmp/main-b6fac8.o: In function `A::A()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN1AC2Ev[_ZN1AC2Ev]+0x15): undefined reference to `std::array<unsigned char, 5ul> A::filledArray<5ul, (unsigned char)65>()'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

seems like clang is does not see, that i instantiate the filledArray function.
if I call filledArray with the proper template arguments in the main or any other function, the warning disappears and clangOut also prints As as expected.

1. am I doing something stupid here?
2. is the gcc version doing what i think (initialise upper with As at compile time)?
3. is this a bug in clang?

Comment: Right, it is a bug in clang. #2 is a nah, it is not doing what i thought. it wasn't executed during compile time, because array::fill() is not a constexpr. In another question the debugger was used with a breakpoint in the constexpr function. When writing constexpr A blah;, it also produces a compile error.

Comment: which also answers question #1. yes, it is stupid. I'll post an answer doing proper compile time initialisation below, but for production i'll just use a const function, because it's much easier to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. am I doing something stupid here?

Yes, the function `filledArray()` always calls a non-constexpr `std::array:fill`, so declaring it `constexpr` is strictly speaking an error (according to [[dcl.constexpr]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#5) "the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required").

> 2. is the gcc version doing what i think (initialise upper with As at compile time)?

Many compilers relax the [[dcl.constexpr]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#5) requirement and silently ignore `constexpr` when it is used in a non-constexpr context. But with optimization on they can also easily see through inline calls such as the construction of `std::array` and `std::array::fill()` and will most probably evaluate your function compile-time, even if it wasn't declared `constexpr` ([demo](https://godbolt.org/g/Hezo7D)).

> 3. is this a bug in clang?

Yes it's a clang bug ([#18781](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18781)).

Clang cannot compile `static constexpr` class members.
It cannot properly "see" when such elements are ODR-used. To verify, you can just place `A::filledArray<5, 'A'>();` by itself somewhere inside `main()`, that will "fix" the compilation (but not the ill-formedness).

Another example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
  constexpr static const char* me = "foo";
};

int main ()
{
  foo f;
  std::cout << f.me << std::endl;
}
```

Changing `f.me` to `foo::me` also "fixes" it.

As a workaround you can change `constexpr` to `const`.

Comment: thanks for finding the bug :) constexpr is totally useless here, as my function contains non-constexpr method calls. I'm surprised that the compiler didn't warn about it.

Answer (score 0):

2. Is it doing what i think? -> no (tested by setting a breakpoint)

the following does (inspired by the answer to [Array Initialisation Compile Time - Constexpr Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940284/))

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, T value>
constexpr T generate_ith_number(const std::size_t) {
static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "T must to be an integral type");
return value;
}

template <typename T, T value, T... Is>
constexpr auto make_sequence_impl(std::integer_sequence<T, Is...>)
{
    return std::integer_sequence<T, generate_ith_number<T, value>(Is)...>{};
}

template <typename T, T value, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto make_sequence()
{
    return make_sequence_impl<T, value>(std::make_integer_sequence<T, N>{});
}

template <typename T, T... Is>
constexpr auto make_array_from_sequence_impl(std::integer_sequence<T, Is...>)
{
    return std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)>{Is...};
}

template <typename Seq>
constexpr auto make_array_from_sequence(Seq)
{
    return make_array_from_sequence_impl(Seq{});
}

typedef unsigned char uchar;

class A {
public:
    template <size_t N, uchar value>
    static inline constexpr std::array<uchar, N> filledArray() {
        return make_array_from_sequence(make_sequence<uchar, value, N>());
    }

    // long route
    std::array<uchar, 5> upper = A::filledArray<5, 'A'>();

    // taking a short cut
    std::array<uchar, 45> blah = make_array_from_sequence_impl(make_sequence<uchar, 'A', 45>()); 

    void dummy() {A::filledArray<5, 'A'>();}    // make clang happy
};

int main() {
    A blah;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        std::cout << blah.upper[i] << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 45; ++i)
        std::cout << blah.blah[i] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

which actually also answers #1. yes, it is stupid trying to optimise code that will never be performance critical, fail at doing so, hit compiler bugs and waste many hours trying to find a solution that is too verbose and too hard to read for production. :D